# 2D Fourier Transform of the PDE $u_{xx}+u_{tt}=g(x,t)$

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

> I am having trouble writing a formal solution to the PDE $$u_{xx}+u_{tt}=g(x,t),$$ for $x\in (-\infty,\infty)$ and $t\in (-\infty,\infty)$.

If I take the Fourier transform of the PDE with respect to $x$ and $t$, I get that $$\hat{u}(\lambda,\mu)=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{g(x,t)}{\lambda^2+\mu^2}e^{-i(\lambda x+\mu t)} \ dx \ dt.$$ But I am having serious problems calculating the inverse Fourier transform of $\hat{u}(\lambda,\mu)$. I get that $$u(x,t)=-\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{g(x,t)}{\lambda^2+\mu^2}e^{-i(\lambda x+\mu t)+i(\lambda x+\mu t)} \ dx \ dt \ d\lambda \ d\mu,$$ which clearly doesn't make sense as the exponential term cancels. It is a bit frustrating as I'm having trouble building on from my knowledge of $1$D Fourier transforms.

Comment: First, the basis of your transforms should have opposite signs in the power of the exponential i.e $$\hat{f}(\lambda) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) e^{\color{red}- i \lambda x} dx \implies f(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \hat{f}(\lambda) e^{\color{orange}+ i \lambda x} d\lambda$$ Secondly, your inverse transform should leave you with a function of $x$ and $t$, so you should only be integrating out $\lambda$ and $\mu$, **not** $\lambda, \mu, x$ and $t$.

Comment: @Mattos I thought my signs are opposite (the $-i$ and the $+i$ in the final equation). For your second point, are you saying the final integral should only contain $d\lambda$ and $d\mu$?

Comment: You will have 4 integrals but you need to introduce a third set of variables!

Comment: @Mattos do we take the Fourier transform w.r.t $x$ first and then take the Fourier transform of this equation w.r.t $y$ (or vice versa) in the very first steps?

Comment: If I remember my measure theory correctly (it's been a while), you need $f$ (viz $\hat{f}$) to be in $L^{1}$ i.e $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert f \rvert dx < \infty$$ in order to ensure it's Fourier transform exists. But if the function is in $L^{1}$, then you can apply [Fubinis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem#Fubini%E2%80%93Tonelli_theorem) and switch the order of integration. So I don't believe it matters which transform you take first, they should both give the same result (provided $g(x,t)$ is 'nice enough' to do everything you need it to do). I could be wrong though.

Comment: @Mattos This looks correct. Lastly, why do $d\lambda \ d\mu$ appear in the inside of the order of integration upon inverting? Why isn't the order of integration of $u(x,y)$ equal to $ds \ d\tau \ d\lambda \ d\mu$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wise to use dummy variables for the first integral, say

$$ \hat u(\lambda,\mu) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\iint_\limits{(s,\tau) \in \Bbb R^2} g(s,\tau) \frac{e^{-i(\lambda s + \mu \tau)}}{\lambda^2 + \mu^2} ds\ d\tau $$

The inverse transform of this is

\begin{align} 
u(x,t) &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\iint_\limits{(\lambda,\mu)\in\Bbb R^2} \hat u(\lambda,\mu)e^{+i(\lambda x + \mu t)} d\lambda d\mu \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\iint_\limits{(s,t)\in\Bbb R^2}g(s,t) \left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\iint_\limits{(\lambda,\mu)\in\Bbb R^2} \frac{e^{+i\big(\lambda(x-s)+\mu(t-\tau)\big)}}{\lambda^2+\mu^2} d\lambda\ d\mu \right)ds\ d\tau
\end{align}

Let $h(x,y)$ be the inverse Fourier transform of $\hat h(\lambda,\mu) = \dfrac{1}{\lambda^2+\mu^2}$, then the result is a convolution:

$$ u(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\iint_\limits{(s,\tau)\in\Bbb R^2} g(s,\tau) h(x-s,t-\tau) ds\ d\tau $$

Comment: Should the order of integration be reversed in your third equation?

Comment: @Bell That's the beauty of it. The order of integration doesn't matter, so we can rearrange the terms and write it in that form

Comment: Fascinating! Why is that? Is it due to Fibini's theorem?